# Generic Method Type Parameter Declaration

Tags: java, generics

So, good ol' *Dietel* states, "All generic method declarations have a **type-parameter section** delimited by **angle brackets** (< and >) that *precedes the methods return type*," (Deitel, 2012, italicized emphasis mine). The example given is as follows:

```
public static < T > void printArray (T[] inputArray)
{
    for (T element : inputArray)
    (
        System.out.printlf("%s", element);
}
```

That makes sense to me. I get that. But, here is my question, not addressed explicitly in the book.

I have a very simple class to demonstrate:

```
public class Pair<F, S> 
{
    private F first;
    private S second;
}
```

Now, according to Deitel, "**ALL**" generic method declarations must contain a type-parameter section. So, naturally, I want to add a `get()` and `set()` method to my class example. So, I do this:

```
public class Pair<F, S>
{
    private F first;
    private S second;

    // Here, I'll do one instead of both for the sake of shortening the code
    public < F > F getF()
    {
        return F;
    }

    // And the Accessor:
    public < F > void setF(F first)
    {
        this.first = first;
    }
}
```

So, here's the deal. The Eclipse IDE gives me a warning ahead of my attempt to compile (the Java version of Intellisense) that states, "The type parameter F is hiding the type F". Now, I don't particularly trust *Dietel* for Java - and am growing to understand that they are not particularly reliable (in that they often leave out important distinctions). So, I went to the [Oracle Documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/types.html) for what I am doing and - *GUESS WHAT* - they mention nothing of the sort, unless you're talking about 'upperbounded' type parameters.

Here's the question (it's threefold):

1. Is the difference here the `static' qualifier, i.e. that the method I am writing appears in a class?
2. What on Earth is *Dietel* doing, particularly as implementation of their suggestions, here, yields a warning?
3. By changing the class type parameters, I get rid of the warning. So, conceptually, what is going on to where the method parameter type is "hiding" the class parameter type?

Comment: You don't have to define it on method level if it is defined on class level.

Comment: There's a difference between a generic method and a generic class.

Comment: @JeroenVannevel Thanks, that's the explicit distinction I was looking for.

Comment: Actually, it would probably help if I read the next freakin' chapter. They seem to have corrected themselves, there.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The JLS specifically designates a generic method as one that declares type parameters. ([JLS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4.4)) So the confusion here is that Deital has said that *"all generic methods have a type parameter section"* but presumably not specifically pointed out that this is their definition. It is more clear to say that *"a generic method is one that has a type parameter section"*.

As noted in a comment, when you have type parameters declared by a class, you do not need to redeclare them at the method. As noted by Eclipse, doing so actually declares new type parameters which hide the ones declared by the class.

When they are declared on the class you can use them directly:

```
class Pair<F, S> {
    F getF() { ... }
    S getS() { ... }
    void setF(F f) { ... }
    void setS(S s) { ... }
}
```

The purpose of a generic method is to use it parametrically. The given example is not particularly good for understanding because the generic type is actually unused: the `printf` overload for Object is called. It can be rewritten without generics with no change to its functionality:

```
public static void printArray(Object[] arr) {
    for(Object o : arr) {
        System.out.printf("%s", o);
    }
}
```

The easiest example for understanding the use of a generic method is the implementation of [`Objects#requireNonNull`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Objects.html#requireNonNull-T-) which is something like this:

```
public static <T> T requireNonNull(T obj) {
    if(obj == null)
        throw new NullPointerException();
    return obj;
}
```

It takes any object and conveniently returns it as a `T`:

```
// T is inferred
String hello = Objects.requireNonNull("hello world");
// T is provided as a witness (rarely necessary)
Integer five = Objects.<Integer>requireNonNull(5);
```

It is the simplest generic method.

Comment: Thank for the time you put into your answer! Wonderful.